# Using a background-image for checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to setup some checkboxes so that when not checked they use one image that I've got and then when checked they used another image. Here's my current checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fordCheckBox" value="Ford">
```

I'm also using the following CSS in order to set the background image for each checkbox.

```
input[type=checkbox][name=fordCheckBox] {
        background:url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/550291079719698432/LbybHjIh.jpeg") no-repeat;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-size: 50%;
    }

    input[type=checkbox][name=fordCheckBox]:checked {
        background:url("http://contentservice.mc.reyrey.net/image_v1.0.0/2267461") no-repeat;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-size: 50%;
    }
```

As you can see in my [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lzmm0qt/) the icons is the correct size but it's never setting the background image like it should be. Any suggestions?

Comment: how your background image suppose to look??? not clear about that??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just do it with label

```
   input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    background:url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/550291079719698432/LbybHjIh.jpeg") no-repeat;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;;
    background-size: 50%;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background:url("http://contentservice.mc.reyrey.net/image_v1.0.0/2267461") no-repeat;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-size: 50%;
}
```

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fordCheckBox" id="Ford" value="Ford">
<label for="Ford"></label>
```

Please check updated jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/s4nr6q3d/

Comment: please change the background image url and then you can see it works.

Comment: How I will do for multiple check box with multiple images. Each check box with different images.

Answer (score 4):

I used this CSS. In this CSS, when checkbox is checked, it puts a tick image on the checkbox. Also it changes the size, color and border of the checkbox by default.

```
    input[type='checkbox'] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #555;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    input[type='checkbox']:checked {
        background-image: url("Images/tick-sm.png");
        background-size: 90%;
        background-position: right center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
```

Replace "Images/tick-sm.png" with your own image.

If you want a different background for the un-checked state too, add the same contents of the second block to first block and replace the image.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't actually try and change the checkbox directly; some browsers will always show the default checkbox.  How it is typically done is by adding a label for the checkbox that is linked to the inputs id field. For example:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='x' name='fordCheckBox'>
<label for='x'></label>
```

Then you set your checkbox to `display: none` and the actual css gets applied to the label instead.  Your selectors should look like this: `input[type=checkbox]:checked + label`

I found this article that will help explain everything and walk you through it step by step:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953

Answer (score 1):

I made an example of **"Use Images Like Checkboxes and Radios Pure Css"**

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gh5kdp?file=index.html)

[image]

[image]

In index.html file:

```
<div class="cont-bg">
  <div class="cont-title">Checkbox</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-1" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-2" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-title">Radio</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-1" />
      <label for="myRadio-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-2" />
      <label for="myRadio-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In style.css file:

```
* {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --transition: 0.15s;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
  --background: #ffc107;
  --box-shadow: #ffc107;
}

.cont-bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle farthest-corner at 7.2% 13.6%,
    rgba(37, 249, 245, 1) 0%,
    rgba(8, 70, 218, 1) 90%
  );
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.cont-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-checkbox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  background: white;
  transition: transform var(--transition);
}

.cont-checkbox:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
}

.cont-checkbox:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--background);
}

input:checked + label img {
  -webkit-filter: none; /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: none;
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

label img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 50% 100%, 0 81%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

label .cover-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--box-shadow);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: transform var(--transition),
    opacity calc(var(--transition) * 1.2) linear;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label .cover-checkbox svg {
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  fill: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.4s ease var(--transition);
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
}

label .info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

I made an example of **"Angular - Use images like checkboxes and radios"**

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-base-simple-scss-hf9hrp?file=src/app/app.component.html)